# mysql_real_escape_string strange apostrophe behaviour?

Tags: php, str-replace, mysql-real-escape-string

I have a form and a user enters eg (note apostrophe at end of string)

```
My Bday'
```

Now, I want to strip apostrophes, simple as that... not escape them, not add slashes just get rid of them

Firstly I have the following:

```
$event_title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['event_title']);

echo "<br /><br /><br />event title is $event_title";
```

Which results in the following being returned:

```
event title is My Bday\\\'
```

Why 3 slashes?

So, then I go ahead and deal with this by using the following:

```
$event_title = str_replace("'", "", $event_title); 

$event_title = stripslashes($event_title);
```

Then I return it again to check results

```
echo "<br /><br /><br />event title is $event_title";
```

I get the following:

```
event title is My Bday\
```

Any ideas what's happening? I simply want to strip apostophes and slashes but somehow it's not happening

magic_quotes_gpc is off by the way

If I don't use stripslashes therefore leaving them in for MySQL to deal with I get the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Private',
event_notes = '' where user_event_id = '35'' at line 3

update user_events set event_date = '2012-11-17', event_title = 'My Bday\\\',
event_vis = 'Private', event_notes = '' where user_event_id = '35'
```

OK, a further EDIT:

I tried this:

```
$event_title = $_POST['event_title'];

$event_title = str_replace("'", "", $event_title);

$event_title = trim($event_title);

$event_title = mysql_real_escape_string($event_title);

echo "<br /><br /><br />event title is $event_title";
```

and I get this:

```
event title is My Bday\\
```

I simply want to get rid of apostrophes, clearly something else is going on here but its got me!

Comment: Although not an answer: you should really read [this](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/3656047#3656047).

Comment: You give what the user has entered, but is that exactly equal to `$_POST['event_title']` before it's escaped?

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string is for data->sanitize->storage and not data->sanitize->output, the data will be displayed correctly if you follow this pattern.
data->sanitize->storage->output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening is this:

`mysql_real_escape_string` escapes all the characters that should be escaped by adding a slash in front of a character being escaped. But adding just a slash will lead to storing the character as unescaped within the DB, therefore also the slash must be escaped prior to inserting...

That's why You have `My BDay\\\'`. If this value is stored into a DB the final result will be `My BDay\'`.

But when You do `str_replace("'", "", 'My BDay\\\'');` You will end up with `My BDay\\\` and after calling `stripslashes` on this You will get `My BDay\` - that is absolutely correct!

So don't bother with how the string looks like after calling `mysql_real_escape_string`, just store that value into the DB and after retrieving it You will end up with `My BDay'` again...

**EDIT** How You come to just one slash from the three after calling `stripslasshes`? The function goes from the start of the string to its end and looks for any slash escaped characters to remove the escaping slash. So it finds first two slashes and removes one, but still two remains (the one just processed and the third one), so it processes next two slasshes it finds that will result in just one slash remaining...

If You'd call stripslashes on the string `My BDay\\\'` - that will lead to `My BDay'`...

**EDIT2** My bad... The next two slashes are added probably because You have `magic_quotes_gpc` ON - turn that off or call `mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($string))`.

Comment: Just updated question, what you're saying SHOULD happen is not - you say: If You'd call stripslashes on the string My BDay\\\' - that will lead to My BDay' - it doesn't in my case I'm afraid - see op - its in that order that i process things

Comment: -1: Simply wrong. `mres` only adds *one* backslash for each character, and that's how it's documented to work; the extra backslashes are coming from somewhere else.

Comment: The original post says I DO NOT have magic_quotes_gpc ON, however, mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($string)) has fixed it - what a b*ll ache! many thanks for persevering mate

Answer (score 0):

One slash to escape the apostrophe, the other to escape the slash that escape the apostrophe.

Internally the mysql interpret the \' how '

Answer (score 0):

in your php settings the string_splash setting is ON and that is why when the string is passed from form - it is already excapped...  Now you using mysql_real_escape_string - which excapes "excape character" as well as single quote as well. and that is why three slashes..

Try using this function - which I use a lot

```
function sanitize( $value )
{
    if( get_magic_quotes_gpc() )
    {
          $value = stripslashes( $value );
    }
    //check if this function exists
    if( function_exists( "mysql_real_escape_string" ) )
    {
          $value = mysql_real_escape_string( $value );
    }
    //for PHP version < 4.3.0 use addslashes
    else
    {
          $value = addslashes( $value );
    }
    return $value;
}
```

It is not specifically for php 4 or older years... The function works to escape string and make sure it does not double escape it ( which is the question beign asked )

if( function_exists( "mysql_real_escape_string" ) ) - this line escapes if the database connection is available  and

else part of that if condition makes sure it works if database connection is not available and  php 4 support is added benifit only...

Comment: why would you assume that he needs php4 support ?